# iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement

Tags: iphone, macos, xcode4

I have submitted my iphone app to itune and got that message as "invalid binary". I got mail from apple is following.

Dear developer,
We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "XYZ". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:
iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5. As of May 1, all new iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. All apps must include a launch image of the appropriate size. Learn more about iPhone 5 support by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

I have include launch image to the appropriate size but i got same asabove problem again and again .
 my mac pc configure are as

Xcode: 4.0
 Mac OS X: 10.6.8(Snow Leopard)
 iPhone OS: 4.3
To resolve this problem it is mandatory to upgrade my MAC OS X:
if no please tell step to resolve this problem . I am facing this problem at 5-6 days before .
Please help me .

Thank You .

Comment: Yes you will need Lion or Mountain Lion, since you need to have the iOS 6 SDK. Updating you OSX version in the only option because the iOS 6 SDK needs Lion or Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you will have to upload your app for iphone 5 also , means you will have to add three default screen for your application , and you will have to upload app by XCode 4.5 , and add armv7s

Since 1 may apple will approve app that will work on iphone 5 .